# FAXCOMEXLIB deprecated?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, fax

I found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692936(v=vs.85).aspx

My development environment is Windows 10 and Visual Studio Community 2015. But I only found FAXCOMLIB in reference. Is .NET not using FAXCOMEXLIB anymore? Can we achieve that with FAXCOMLIB? It seems some class/member not available in FAXCOMLIB.

I am trying to send fax using this. Should I change development environment to do this? Please let me know

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely you did not look hard enough and went for the first one whose name started with "fax".  You need "Microsoft Fax Service Extended COM Type Library".

Comment: Sorry sir @HansPassant, my apologies, thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add to a COM reference and browse to the file FXSCOMEX.dll in C:\Windows\System32.